# Arithmetic overflow error for dates above 12th of any month

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have created a table in MS SQL 2008 which is of type "datetime".

In front end i have created a input box which reads the date from calendar control.

As soon as user selects the date from calendar control, input box is populated with selected date.

```
TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

then i am adding the contents like as below to SQL Command

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code works fine when I select dates till 11th, i.e. 11-04-2013, as soon i select 12-04-2013 and any date above 12th of any month, I am getting exception "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime"

Let me know where I have  gone wrong.

Comment: Where you're getting the error? In the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly add date to parameter, you don't have to format it.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",  Calendar1.SelectedDate);
```

SqlServer `DateTime` column in irespective of format. The reason you are getting the overflow is because it is considering first part as `Month` and since there are only `12` months in an year, you are getting the error. Formatting is only useful for displaying dates.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the current culture your system is using. I believe SQL Server expected date in the form of `yyyy-MM-dd` and somehow your code is interchanging day with month

Try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", TextBox1.Text));
```

Or convert to date

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text));
```